# Solving a pde with laplace transforms

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Consider the following problem:
$$∂g/∂t − ∂/∂x(x^{2−a} ∂g/∂x) = δ(x − ξ)δ(t − τ )$$ with $0 < x, ξ < ∞, 0 < t, τ,$
where the solution remans finite over the entire interval and initially
$g(x, 0|ξ, τ ) = 0$. Find the Green's function for this problem.

First we performed a laplace transform for the time dependent term. Afterwards the following hint was given: (Hint: take
the Laplace transform and introduce new variables for $a≠0$ as $y=\frac{2\sqrt{s}}{|a|}x^{\frac{a}{2}}$ and $ η = \frac{2\sqrt{s}}{|a|}ξ^{\frac{a}{2}}$ and $ G(x, s|ξ, τ ) = \frac{2(xξ)^(\frac{a−1}{2})}{|a|}F(y,η)e^{-sτ}$
Next transform back.)

We did the derivation in the original problem and put in the expression for $G$. This yielded a long expression and we were not able to express everything in terms of $y$ and $η$.

Could someone help us solving this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The PDE in question looks like a Fokker-Planck equation with no drift and with position dependent volatility. Can you please tell me why were you asked to solve this PDE in the first place? What kind of processes are described by the equation?

Answer (score 0):

This question is more complicated than I thought but the hint is correct and leads to a right direction. Let us Laplace-transform the original PDE first. We define $\tilde{g}(x,s) := \int\limits_0^\infty g(x,t) \exp(-t s) d t$ and we have:
\begin{equation}
-g(x,0) + s \tilde{g}(x,s) - \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[x^{2-a} \frac{\partial \tilde{g}}{\partial x} \right] = \delta(x - \xi) e^{-\tau s}
\end{equation}
The first term on the left hand side vanishes by assumption.  Now we change variables. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{d y}{d x}  \cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial y} = \sqrt{s} \cdot \mbox{sign(a)} x^{a/2-1}  \frac{\partial }{\partial y} \\
\delta(y - \eta) = \frac{|a|}{2 \sqrt{s}} \delta(x^{a/2} - \xi^{a/2}) = \frac{\delta(x-\xi)}{\sqrt{s} \xi^{a/2-1}} \\
\tilde{g}(x,s) = \frac{2 (x \xi)^{(a-1)/2}}{|a|} F(y,\eta) e^{-s \tau} \quad (i)
\end{eqnarray}
Inserting all this into the Laplace-transformed PDE we get:
\begin{equation}
F(y,\eta) - y^{-1/a} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[ y^{2/a-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} y^{1-1/a} F(y,\eta) \right] = \frac{1}{y} \cdot \left(\frac{y}{\eta}\right)^{1/a} \cdot \delta(y-\eta)
\end{equation}
We expand the second term on the left hand side and we get:
\begin{equation}
F(y,\eta) - \frac{-(-1+a)^2 F(y,\eta) + a^2 y \partial_y F(y,\eta) + a^2 y^2 \partial_y^2 F(y,\eta)}{a^2 y^2} = \frac{1}{y} \cdot \left(\frac{y}{\eta}\right)^{1/a} \cdot \delta(y-\eta)
\end{equation}
We multiply both sides by $a^2 y^2$ and we get:
\begin{equation}
y^2 \partial_y^2 F(y,\eta) + y \partial_y F(y,\eta) - \left[y^2 + \left(\frac{-1+a}{a}\right)^2\right] F(y,\eta) = -  \left(\frac{y}{\eta}\right)^{1/a} y \delta(y-\eta)
\end{equation}
We recognise the Bessel equation with a purely imaginary argument  and a source term. Therefore the solution reads:
\begin{equation}
F(y,\eta) = \left\{
\begin{array}{cc} C^{+}_+ I_{(-1+a)/a}(y) + C^{+}_- I_{(1-a)/a}(y) & \mbox{if $ y> \eta$} \\
C^{-}_+ I_{(-1+a)/a}(y) + C^{-}_- I_{(1-a)/a}(y) & \mbox{if $ y< \eta$}
\end{array}
\right. \quad (ii)
\end{equation}
where the constants $C^{\pm}_{\pm}$ depend on $\eta$ only. Out of the four constants two are eliminated from the following relations:
\begin{eqnarray}
F(\eta+  \epsilon, \eta) - F(\eta - \epsilon, \eta) = 0  \\
F^{(1,0)}(\eta+  \epsilon, \eta) - F^{(1,0)}(\eta - \epsilon, \eta) = - \frac{1}{\eta} 
\end{eqnarray}
which give:
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{c} C_+^+ - C_+^{-} \\ C_-^+ - C_-^-\end{array} 
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} I_{+\theta}(\eta) & I_{-\theta}(\eta) \\ I^{'}_{+\theta}(\eta) & I^{'}_{-\theta}(\eta) \end{array}
\right)^{-1}
\cdot
\left(
\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ -\frac{1}{\eta}\end{array}
\right) \quad (iii)
\end{equation}
where $\theta := (-1+a)/a$.
By combining equations (i), (ii) and (iii) we get the final solution in Laplace domain. Going to the time domain is trivial because  the inverse Laplace transform of $e^{-s \tau}$ is just $\delta(t-\tau)$.